# Probability of event for LogNormal Distribution

Tags: standard-deviation, lognormal-distribution

This is a pretty elementary question, but I can't find an answer to it!

Assuming I have a lognormal distribution represented by  $\log(X)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

How do I interpret the likelihood of an event occurring in $X$ based on the $\sigma$ of $\log(X)?$

Would it be correct to state :

1. that $68\%$ of the observations of $X$ lie between $\exp{(\mu-\sigma)}$ and $\exp{(\mu+\sigma)}?$

OR

2. Must the Mean and Variance of $X$ be calculated based on the parameters of $log(X)$

where $Mean$ = $\exp(\mu + 0.50\sigma^2)$
and $Variance$ = $\exp(2\mu + \sigma^2) × (\exp(\sigma^2) − 1)$

(2) Does not seem sensible as it's possible to have  standard deviation greater than the mean when $X$ contains only non negative numbers.

Comment: Your item "1." is *nearly* a correct statement but is not correct, since if you're talking about "the observations" you're referring to some sample, in which case "68.27%" is the expected value of the proportion but the actual proportion is a random variable (a scaled binomial), whose deviation from that expected proportion will be in proportion to $1/\sqrt{n}$. I am not sure I follow what you're getting at with your item 2.

Comment: Thanks Glen. I think for (2), I was just getting confused in what extra information the estimator was giving when I already had $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for $X$. Thanks for confirming (1).